# (From Awodey) Prove $(A\times B)^C\cong A^C\times B^C$

Tags: category-theory

This is an exercise from Awodey's category theory, namely exercise 2 in Chapter 6.

> Prove $(A\times B)^C\cong A^C\times B^C$

The following is the solution in the textbook:

[image]

(Please ignore the "$g$" stuffs )

Once I encountered this problem, the first idea of mine is to define $f:(A\times B)^C \to A^C\times B^C$ as $\alpha(\in (A\times B)^C)\mapsto (\pi_1\circ \alpha,\pi_2\circ \alpha)$ where the $\pi$'s are projections.
And I can take the inverse to be $(p\in A^C,q\in B^C)\mapsto (c\mapsto (p(c),q(c)))$ **I wonder if my thoughts are doable.**

The solution given in the textbook seems more complicated, trying to understand it, I chased the map defined here, I checked it for the $f$ part and the output consists with the map I defined.

But I just realized something that let me feel very worry: What I did is defining a **map**, not a general arrow. And when I chased the diagram, I took $A^C$ to be the collection of maps $C\to A$, but I think I cannot do like this because exponential is not defined as a collection of maps or even arrows, it is defined as an object which satisfies the UMP of exponential, we do not know how does its "elements" looks like.

**So the following is what I am asking about**:

Any comment to my thoughts above? I am self-studing. Any guidence would be very appreciate.

If possible, could someone gives a detailed procedure of chasing the definition of the arrow $f$ to show that it is an isomorphism?

Thanks!

Comment: As you rightly say, your argument holds when you think of your objects as sets and sets of arrows: however, if you try to write your definition "element-less" (only referring to special arrows) you'll see that your definition and Awodey's are pretty much the same thing - the only problem is that when dealing with categories properties which might be naturally thought in terms of elements must be restated for arrows satisfying special properties

Comment: There's a general philosophy that "arrow with codomain $X$" is a good substitute for the notion of "element of $X$", which we call a "generalized element". Even if you don't dive into the internal language, usually all you have to do with these sorts of arguments is translate the element-based formulas into the corresponding arrows and plug in a suitably generic element; typically taking an appropriate identity arrow to be the generic element is informative. e.g. $\alpha = 1_{(A \times B)^C}$. For the inverse arrow, take $p,q$ to be the relevant projection maps defined on $A^C \times B^C$.

Comment: Just for reference, the quick way of proving this once you're comfortable with adjoints is as follows: $(-)^C$ is a right adjoint thus it preserves limits and in particular products. $\square$ Alex Kruckman's proof *is* the general proof for arbitrary limits and arbitrary right adjoints just specialized to products and $(-)^C$. The general proof is that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove that $ff^{-1} = 1_{A^C \times B^C}$ and $f^{-1}f = 1_{(A \times B)^C}$, we need the following lemma:

> **Lemma**. For any $f \colon Y \times C \to Z$ and $g\colon X \to Y$,
>   $$\lambda f g = \lambda(f (g \times 1_C)).$$

For a proof of the lemma see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1070562) by Hanno to a previous question.

Now we can prove that $f$ is an isomorphism. The first direction:
\begin{align}
f f^{-1} & = \langle \lambda (\pi_1 \overline{1_{(A \times B)^C}}), \lambda (\pi_2 \overline{1_{(A \times B)^C}}) \rangle \lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle \\
& = \langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle \lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle \\
& = \langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon) \lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle, \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle \rangle \\
& = \langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon (\lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle \times 1_C)), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon (\lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle \times 1_C)) \rangle \\
& = \langle \lambda (\pi_1 \overline{\lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle}), \lambda (\pi_2 \overline{\lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle}) \rangle \\
& = \langle \lambda (\pi_1 \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle), \lambda (\pi_2 \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle) \rangle \\
& = \langle \lambda \overline{\pi_1}, \lambda \overline{\pi_2} \rangle \\
& = \langle \pi_1, \pi_2 \rangle \\
& = 1_{A^C \times B^C}.
\end{align}
The other direction:
\begin{align}
f^{-1} f & = \lambda \langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle \langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle \\
& = \lambda (\langle \overline{\pi_1}, \overline{\pi_2} \rangle (\langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle \times 1_C)) \\
& = \lambda (\langle \overline{\pi_1} (\langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle \times 1_C), \overline{\pi_2} (\langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle \times 1_C) \rangle) \\
& = \lambda (\langle \epsilon (\pi_1 \times 1_C) (\langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle \times 1_C), \epsilon (\pi_2 \times 1_C) (\langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle \times 1_C) \rangle) \\
& = \lambda (\langle \epsilon ((\pi_1 \langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle) \times 1_C), \epsilon ((\pi_2 (\langle \lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon), \lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \rangle) \times 1_C) \rangle) \\
& = \lambda (\langle \epsilon (\lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon) \times 1_C), \epsilon (\lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon) \times 1_C) \rangle) \\
& = \lambda (\langle \overline{\lambda (\pi_1 \epsilon)}, \overline{\lambda (\pi_2 \epsilon)} \rangle) \\
& = \lambda (\langle \pi_1 \epsilon, \pi_2 \epsilon \rangle) \\
& = \lambda (\langle \pi_1, \pi_2 \rangle \epsilon) \\
& = \lambda \epsilon \\
& = 1_{(A \times B)^C}.
\end{align}

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks a lot and happy new year!

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it's another way to approach questions like this (if you know Yoneda's Lemma).

Look at $\mathrm{Hom}(X,A)$ or $\mathrm{Hom}(A,X)$ for an arbitrary object $X$, and use universal properties of $A$ and $B$ to show that this is naturally isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}(X,B)$ or $\mathrm{Hom}(B,X)$. Then it follows that $A\cong B$ by Yoneda's Lemma.

In this case, for any object $X$, we have the chain of natural isomorphisms:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Hom}(X,(A\times B)^C) &\cong \mathrm{Hom}(X\times C,A\times B)\\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}(X\times C,A)\times \mathrm{Hom}(X\times C,B)\\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,A^C)\times \mathrm{Hom}(X,B^C)\\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,A^C\times B^C)
\end{align*}
So by Yoneda's Lemma, $(A\times B)^C \cong A^C\times B^C$.

Comment: This is certainly the way I'd think about the isomorphism $(A\times B)^C\cong A^C\times B^C$, and I conjecture that (1) it's also the way Awodey thinks about this isomorphism, (2) the formula in the question was obtained by laboriously chasing through these bijections between Hom-sets, and (3) the best way to understand the formula in the question is to laboriously reverse the work that went into (2).

Comment: Thanks! I would go back to read this once I come to this stage. Happy new year!

Comment: @AndreasBlass I don't think the definitions of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ were obtained by diagram chasing. In fact, they can be easily recovered from the $\lambda$-terms
$$\langle \lambda x. \mathrm{fst}(\phi x), \lambda x. \mathrm{snd}(\phi x) \rangle : A^C \times B^C \quad (\phi: (A \times B)^C)$$
and
$$\lambda x. \langle \mathrm{fst}(\psi) x, \mathrm{snd}(\psi) x \rangle : (A \times B)^C \quad (\psi: A^C \times B^C)$$
which in turn should be as easy to define as their counterparts in $\mathrm{Set}$ if one is familiar with $\lambda$-calculus.

Comment: @LucaBressan One could argue that (simply typed) $\lambda$-calculus _is_ diagram chasing in cartesian closed categories...